# How to prevent multiple joins to the same table when using PredicateBuilder

Tags: c#

In this example I am using the NorthWind database supplied by MS.

I am trying to use a predicate builder to assemble multiple

```
Expression<Func<T,bool>>
```

into a single expression tree. It mostly works great in my opinion, but there is one major flaw that I can't seem to address.

I currently have two expressions defined as such:

```
Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> UnitPriceLessThan2 = c => 
        c.Orders.Any(o => o.Order_Details.Any(d => d.Product.UnitPrice <= 2));

Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> UnitPriceGreaterThan5 = c => 
        c.Orders.Any(o => o.Order_Details.Any(d => d.Product.UnitPrice >= 5));
```

I use the [universal predicate builder from Pete Montgomery](http://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/) to OR these two together like such:

```
Expression<Func<Customer,bool>> PriceMoreThan5orLessThan2 = 
         UnitPriceLessThan2.Or(UnitPriceGreaterThan5);
```

Both of those expressions need to navigate to the Product entity through the same path, so it makes sense to reuse the same sub query for both conditions. If I was just manually writing the condition it would look something like this:

```
Expression<Func<Customer,bool>> PriceMoreThan5orLessThan2 = c => 
        c.Orders.Any(o => 
            o.Order_Details.Any(d => d.Product.UnitPrice >= 5 || 
                                d.Product.UnitPrice <= 2));
```

However, because of the requirements to build these predicates dynamically, I can't do that because there would be hundreds of possible combinations...or more.

So my question is how can I prevent LINQ to Entities from creating a query like this:

```
SELECT 
/*all the customer columns*/
FROM [dbo].[Customers] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ( EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent2].[OrderID] AS [OrderID]
        FROM [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE [Extent1].[CustomerID] = [Extent2].[CustomerID]
    )  AS [Project1]
    WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM  [dbo].[Order Details] AS [Extent3]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[ProductID] = [Extent4].[ProductID]
        WHERE ([Project1].[OrderID] = [Extent3].[OrderID]) AND ([Extent4].[UnitPrice] <= cast(2 as decimal(18)))
    )
)) OR ( EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent5].[OrderID] AS [OrderID]
        FROM [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent5]
        WHERE [Extent1].[CustomerID] = [Extent5].[CustomerID]
    )  AS [Project4]
    WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM  [dbo].[Order Details] AS [Extent6]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent7] ON [Extent6].[ProductID] = [Extent7].[ProductID]
        WHERE ([Project4].[OrderID] = [Extent6].[OrderID]) AND (([Extent7].[UnitPrice] >= cast(5 as decimal(18)))))));
```

The problem being that we've created two EXISTS sub queries when we really only needed one.

Instead I would like the query to look like this:

```
SELECT 
/*all the customer columns*/
FROM [dbo].[Customers] AS [Extent1]
WHERE( EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent5].[OrderID] AS [OrderID]
        FROM [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent5]
        WHERE [Extent1].[CustomerID] = [Extent5].[CustomerID]
    )  AS [Project4]
    WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM  [dbo].[Order Details] AS [Extent6]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent7] ON [Extent6].[ProductID] = [Extent7].[ProductID]
        WHERE ([Project4].[OrderID] = [Extent6].[OrderID]) AND (([Extent7].[UnitPrice] >= cast(5 as decimal(18))) OR ([Extent7].[UnitPrice] <= cast(2 as decimal(18))))
    )
))
```

Can I somehow store and reuse the navigation path as an expression and then inject the two conditions with their appropriate user supplied operators and values into that?

Or use some expression visitor implementation to...I don't know what exactly, find and replace?

Thank you for reading my rather lengthy question :)

Comment: The code is doing exactly what you are telling it to do. If the result is what you are after then I probably wouldn't try to 'fix' this. If you did want to fix it you would need to try and move the OR logic into the filter on `Order_Details.Any()` instead of at the Customer level. You'll need to decide if that makes sense for your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off a small trick to increase readability, add these within your namespace, not needed for this to work but I find it makes the code easier to read:

```
namespace YourNameSpaceHere
{
    using DetailPredicate = Expression<Func<Order_Details, bool>>;
    using CustomerPredicate = Expression<Func<Customer, bool>>;
```

Secondly, create a list of Order Detail predicates, when all possible Order Detail predicates have been added we aggregate them and apply them:

```
public void foo()
{
  // List of predicates for order detail
  var predicates = new List<DetailPredicate>();

  // Logic to determine what predicates get added to list
  if(somelogic)
    predicates.Add(d => d.Product.UnitPrice >= 5);

  if(somethingelse)    
    predicates.Add(d => d.Product.UnitPrice <= 2);

  // Default to true
  var whereDetails = PredicateBuilder.True<Order_Details>();

  if (predicates.Any())
  {
     // Aggregate predicates with OR in between
     whereDetails = predicates.Aggregate(PredicateBuilder.Or);
  }

  // Apply aggregate
  CustomerPredicate PriceMoreThan5orLessThan2 = c => 
      c.Orders.Any(o => 
          o.Order_Details.Any(whereDetails);
```